# Intersection of sets of intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find a sequence of open and dense subsets of the reals, $V_j$ , such that $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty V_j = \{x\in Q \}$, where Q is the set of all rational numbers.

**My Answer**

I am trying $V_j = \{(x-\frac1j, x+\frac1j) : \text{x is rational}\}$ . I already have the proof of it being both open and dense, but now, I am questioning about how to take the intersection of all the V's. I know that $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty (x-\frac1j, x+\frac1j) = x$ , but I am completely unsure of what to do with a set of such intervals.

Could I, if A,B,C,D are intervals such that $V_1 = \{A,B\}$, $V_2=\{C,D\}$ state that $V_1 \cap V_2 = \{ A\cap C, A\cap D, B\cap C, B\cap D\}$? If so, what would allow me to do that? Would It have to be proven rigorously? Also, is there an easier way to do this, and if so, what is it?

Comment: The motivation for the choice is that the respective elements of $V_j$ form nested intervals.

Comment: Also, if intersection of sets of intervals works that way, then, since I already know the intersection of the corresponding elements to be the rationals, I could show that the intersection of non-corresponding elements is the null set (should be easy enough), and that it would not count.

Somehow, I am cringing at this approach...

Comment: Unfortunately your approach won't quite work, because each $V_j$ is actually all of $\Bbb R$ (do you see why?). (Also, note that $\{x\in\Bbb Q\}$ is just a longer way of writing $\Bbb Q$.)

Comment: When you say $\bigcap_j V_j$ do you mean $\bigcap_j\bigcup V_j$?

Comment: (By the way, you cannot do what you are trying.)

Comment: @GregMartin I am taking a collection of intervals, not the union of them all. You are right in that every real number is in each $V_j$, but a collection of sets is not necessarily a union of sets. $\{\{2,3\},\{3,5\}\} \neq \{2,3,5\}$

Comment: This is because $\{2,3,5\}$ is **not** a subset of $\{\{2,3\},\{3,5\}\}$ in much the same way that the reals is not a subset of any of the $V_j$, which must happen if the sets are to be equal to each other.

Comment: I agree that there's a difference between $V_j$ being a set of reals and $V_j$ being a set of sets of reals. I see now that your definition of $V_j$ is indeed the latter. However, the problem asks for the former, so I think you will have to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think $\mathbb{Q}$ can be written like that.

First the irrational numbers $\mathbb{I}$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets $A_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$, just enumerate $\mathbb{Q}=\{q_i\}$ and take $A_n=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{q_i\}$

If we were able to write $\mathbb{Q}$ as the countable intersection of open sets $B_n$, each $B_n$ would have to be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense. Thus we know $\emptyset=\mathbb{I}\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is a countable intersection of open dense subsets. But this contradicts the Baire category theorem, since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Comment: So, I am confused. Are you saying that, no matter how $V_j$ is picked, the intersection of them all will never produce the set of rational numbers, or are you saying that just my answer is wrong?

Comment: @MikeWarren I am saying $\mathbb{Q}$ can't be written as countable intersection of open sets

Comment: I was never taught the Baire category theorem. Also, where is the "irrationals intersection the rationals" coming from? $A_n$?

Comment: @MikeWarren one version of the theorem states a countable intersection of open dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ must be dense. If each of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{I}$ is countable intersection of open dense sets, I take $\mathbb{I}\cap \mathbb{Q}$ which is empty to draw a contradiction.